# What are TPS Reports?

Tags: office-space

In the 1999 film *[Office Space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Space)*, there is an ongoing joke about Peter Gibbons not putting cover sheets on his TPS Reports, and multiple people reminding him or showing incredulity at him not doing that.

I work in the IT industry, but I have never heard of TPS reports (except in reference to this film). Are they something that was invented specifically for *Office Space*? Or are they are something that only exists in more specialized areas?

Comment: TPS reports are what the screenwriting industry refers to as "McGuffins".

Answer (score 59, accepted):

**TEST PROGRAM SET**

According to director Mike Judge, TPS reports stand for Test Program Set in the [movie](https://www.rollingstone.com/culture/news/office-space-cast-reunite-at-10th-anniversary-screening-of-mike-judges-cult-film-20090209).

> I guess I can settle this once and for all," Mike Judge, the movie's
>   writer and director, said of the dreaded report his protagonist, Peter
>   Gibbons, failed to attach a cover sheet to, despite his eight bosses'
>   memo to do so. "When I was an engineer, it stood for **Test Program Set**.
>   Isn't that exciting?"

In popular culture, TPS Reports are defined as mindless paperwork in an office [environment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TPS_report):

> After its use in the comedic 1999 film Office Space, "TPS report" has
>   come to connote pointless, mindless paperwork, and an example of
>   "literacy practices" in the work environment that are "meaningless
>   exercises imposed upon employees by an inept and uncaring management"
>   and "relentlessly mundane and enervating". According to the film's
>   writer and director Mike Judge, the abbreviation stood for "Test
>   Program Set" in the movie. In the movie, multiple managers and
>   coworkers inquire about a single error that Peter Gibbons makes in
>   utilizing a wrong cover sheet to send his TPS reports. It is used by
>   Gibbons as an example that he has eight different persons he directly
>   reports to.

There is also a definition in the [urban dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=tps%20report) regarding TPS reports defining them as Total Pointless Stuff (among other things).

Comment: I recall Chandler Bing having similar 'important' paperwork to so, the name 'weenis' springs to mind. Anyone recall if they also used 'TPS'?

Comment: The possibility amuses me that Mike Judge himself might misremember the abbreviation from his engineering time (or his former team didn't know better) and it really _was_ the abbreviation for the IEEE 829 Test Procedure Specification mentioned in another answer.

Comment: @Dubu Hmmmm...I don't know.  I will just have to take Mr. Judge at what he says, since it relates to the movie :)

Comment: @steelersquirrel Your answer is certainly correct.  If the director says so, TPS _in the movie_ did mean "Test Program Set." Whatever other meanings might exist in the real world.

Comment: @Dubu Sure.  I understand what you are saying, though.  I mean...this _is_ the same guy who created Beavis and Butthead :P

Comment: @Tetsujin It was WENUS, for Weekly Estimated Net Usage Systems (or Statistics, they weren't consistent).

Comment: @Dubu : If it did come from IEEE 829 and change, it's even funnier. In enterprise situations, an term like "Test Procedure Specification" might come from a common standard like IEEE 829. The company adopts it, but writing "Test Procedure Specification" over and over is irritating, so people started writing "TPS". The company hired new engineers, they see "TPS" but don't know where it came from. Someone mistakenly calls it a "Test Program Set", and it catches on. Now that's the term the company uses, even though it doesn't actually mean it. Someone updates a process document, and now it sticks.

Comment: This is clearly the right answer, since it comes from the director, but TPS (in an IT context) can also stand for Transactions Per Second. That's what it's used for in my office, and we run reports on it.

Comment: You used Urban Dictionary as a serious reference? Give me a few minutes and I'll put something more interesting up there to quote...

Comment: @T.E.D.I was also surprised when I saw UD quoted in more formal contexts but this practice is becoming more common. It's as reliable as wikipedia, after all. UD was cited as evidence for a 2013 armed robbery conviction in Wisconsin and apparently some law journal has created the standard means to reference UD.

Comment: @T.E.D. I wasn't using urban dictionary as any kind of reference.  I included it in my answer to show the relevance of this term in pop culture.  I certainly didn't get my answer from urban dictionary...I fail to understand what is a serious reference from urban dictionary.

Comment: @Segfault - No, it is nowhere near as reliable as Wikipedia. WP has forces that at least try to cull crap from it. The only real useful information a person can really get from UD is that the term really is "A Thing".

Comment: Leavit to Squirrel, on  network choke full of programmers, to be able to asnwer a programming question better than anyone :P

Answer (score 19):

The [Wikipedia post](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/TPS_report) for TPS reports (yes, it exists) lists the following definition, from the Institute of Electrical and Electronics Engineers:

> IEEE 829 – Test Procedure Specification
>   The Test Procedures are developed from both the Test Design and the Test Case Specification. The document describes how the tester will physically run the test, the physical set-up required, and the procedure steps that need to be followed. The standard defines ten procedure steps that may be applied when running a test.

Comment: Never believe Wikipedia. The claim that it derives from IEEE 829 is mere conjecture, and a doubtful one at that.